# Multiple roles with different attributes Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 roles for users: Admin, Editor, Normal user, and made a seperate table for roles, but my problem is that the (normal user) role have much more attributes/entries than the editor or the admin.

Whats the best practice for it?

Should I stick to the Users table and add those attributes as nullable? since the admin/editor does not need to fill it.

or make a new user_details table with one to one relation with the user?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with a `user_details` table in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I often put non required fields for the other users nullable in users table migration file,
And force them to be filled with code or logic (Request file).
You can use in request validation `required_if:role,normal`

Comment: so in my case required_if:role_id,3 while setting them as nullable? since roles are in different table, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, You can also cache the role_id if you want to do a search of which id is your normal role, It may be that the normal role is not the id 3, So you will have to query roles table to get normal role id, but if its static, you're right